# Windows server 2012 standard activation fails with 0x80072EE2

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows, activation

I am facing a weird problem trying to activate a virtual server running windows server 2012 standard edition: in the end it ends up with 0x80072EE2 error (which should be a timeout).

The key is received as a retail from Microsoft under MPN  and it is not a KMS activation. The output of slmgr /dlv (translated from russian :) goes hereafter:

```
Name: Windows(R), ServerStandard edition
Description: Windows(R) Operating System, RETAIL channel
Activation ID: some_big_hex_number
Application ID: another_big_hex
Extended PID: a-lot-of-digits
Installation ID: 257068649_digits_here_07675843
Licensing URL: https://activation.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLActivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
Validation URL: https://validation.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx
Partial product key: M***W
Licensing state: notification
Notification reason: 0xC004F009 (grace period expired)
Re-activations remaining: 1000
Trusted time: 29.10.2013 22:11:51
```

Both URLs (licensing and validation) are accessible from the server in discussion, however activation keeps failing. There are also two events in application log, 1014 and 8200, both from Security-SPP stating the licensing error with the same 0x80072EE2 error. 
I have reviewed MS articles on the subject - nothing helped so far.

Comment: What does `slmgr /rearm` do?

Comment: Did you try google? I find references to that error code including one linking to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/836941/en-gb that indicates the error mans internet timeout. May be time to check those licensing url
s whether they are firewall blocked somewhere.

Comment: @TomTom, I have checked them -- IE opens both fine.

Comment: @NathanC, /rearm -> Success.

Comment: Any help on this? I am having the same issue and the License URL returns "Server Error in '/SLActivateProduct' Application." and Validation URL returns "Server Error in '/SLWGA' Application." (both URL from slmgr /dlv)